# Troubleshooting with installation newrelic agent on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, newrelic

Trying to install java agent on tomcat.
successfully run

```
java -jar newrelic.jar install
```

then run apache, but not see any newrilc initialization messages in catalina out, and not found any logs in newrelic directory.

Answer (score 0):

General guidance on this install process:
The script should print out a good amount of detail on what it's done, including where it detected your Tomcat instance. If nothing's showing up in your CLI, then it's likely you haven't started the install script.

You can use `-h` to see usage help, and `-s /path/to/applicationserver` if you want to make sure the script find your web app. Note that a clear error message should show up if the install script can't find your web app.

The install script is fairly simple, and you can perform a manual install with the steps [in the New Relic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-manual-installation) (broken out by framework).

Comment: install script successfully installed in catalina.sh.
But after running tomcat nothing happen. 

Should there be a any message in catalina.out about starting newrelic agent?

Comment: I download new (clean)tomcat and try install again. All ok. 
It seems it's my local problem! Thank.

Comment: Good to hear! the answer to your question in a comment is yes, you should see the New Relic jar getting opened in the the catalina.out